# How to show GoldenDict in system tray?

Tags: 11.04, panel, dictionary

I have just installed GoldenDict on Ubuntu 11.04, but the system tray icon is missing. Is there any way to show the GoldenDict system tray on Ubuntu 11.04?

I have tried to 'whitelist' it via dconf-edior :
`['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'GoldenDict', 'hp-systray']` but it doesn't seem to work.

If it it's impossible to get the system tray icon to show, is there an other dictionary that will let me search for words from the system tray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Open a terminal and type this code : 
`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'goldendict']"`

2.And then check `enable system tray icon`: 
[image]

3.Log out and log in.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you binarylife! This solved the problem :) I had already tired to add it to the whitelist, but I guess you have to use small letters. I also had to check 'Start to system tray' and 'Close to system tray', but now it works! :)

Comment: @JeppeE , Yeah, your problem was with the code, by the way glad to hear that it worked:).

Comment: In my case it returns " "com.canonical.Unity.Panel"  no such schema"

Answer (score 3):

You have to whitelist GoldenDict if you want to allow them to access the system tray.

Firstly install dconf-tools from the software center ( or by [clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/dconf-tools))
Then Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `dconf-editor` and run it.

[image: dconf-editor alt-f2 dialog]

Now navigate to Desktop -> Unity -> Panel.

[image: configuration editor (dconf-editor) desktop.unity.panel]

Now change the value of  systray-whitelist to

```
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'goldendict']
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 11.04 in classic mode and the NNTPgrab and Skype icons were missing. Took me several days searching for a solution, and finally found this command in terminal:

```
gconftool –recursive-unset /apps/panel
```

The system tray and taskbar will disapear, but after reboot everything is back, and minimizing NNTPgrab and closing Skype to an icon in the systemtray worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, GoldenDict startup to system tray can fail systematically due to a racing condition. In my case, his happened to on one of five Xubuntu LTS 14.04 systems. The solution is rather easy. Create a `~/bin/sleep-goldendict` delayed startup script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
goldendict
exit
```

Be sure to make this script executable with `chmod +x sleep-goldendict`.
Finally, change the GoldenDict entry under `Application Autostart`, making it refer to the full path of the newly created startup script. GoldenDict is a great dictionary application. It would be a pity to miss out on it.