# Goldendict tray icon stopped appearing in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, panel, goldendict

I really liked the functionality where you could highlight the word and goldendict would show the meaning in a small window right next to it, however this isn't working anymore and not even the tray icon is showing.

I looked up a few solutions and found this solution: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42958/how-to-show-goldendict-in-system-tray). I tried it and got the following error:
`No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Panel”`
So I dug a bit more in dconf-editor and found I don't have Unity panel but instead have org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.

So I'm thinking maybe someone can tell me the right command to do the same thing but with ibus panel instead of unity panel.

Thanks a lot.

I already tried `gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'goldendict']"`

But it returns an error:
`No such key “systray-whitelist”`

**Relevant information:** I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (latest updated). I tried all the solutions on the post I linked to.

Extensions I have installed:

1. **Caffeine** by eon
2. **Clipboard** Indicator by Tudmotu
3. **Desktop Icons** by rastersoftHide (deactivated)
4. **Hide Top Bar** by tuxor1337
5. **Ubuntu AppIndicators** by didrocks (deactivated)

Fixes I've tried:

1. Deactivating all of extensions and just running goldendict.
2. Reinstalling goldendict (also deleting .config/goldendict and .goldendict folders)

Please help :(

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629430/goldendict-stopped-showing-icon-in-tray-ubuntu20).

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1308526/edit) your question and add more details?  Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 20.10?  What distro are you using like Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc.  In your link, the very last answer is the most recent as back in 2014.  Did you try that?

Comment: @Terrance I did the edits.

Comment: Distro: Ubuntu.